# Spark show cost based optimizer statistics

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have tried to enable the Spark cbo by setting the property in spark-shell
`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.cbo.enabled", true)`

I am now running `spark.sql("ANALYZE TABLE events COMPUTE STATISTICS").show`

Running this query doesn't show me any statistics `spark.sql("select * from events where eventID=1").explain(true)`

Running this on Spark 2.2.1

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from events where eventID=1").explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [buyDetails.capacity#923, buyDetails.clearingNumber#924, buyDetails.leavesQty#925L, buyDetails.liquidityCode#926, buyDetails.orderID#927, buyDetails.side#928, cancelQty#929L, capacity#930, clearingNumber#931, contraClearingNumber#932, desiredLeavesQty#933L, displayPrice#934, displayQty#935L, eventID#936, eventTimestamp#937L, exchange#938, executionCodes#939, fillID#940, handlingInstructions#941, initiator#942, leavesQty#943L, nbbPrice#944, nbbQty#945L, nboPrice#946, ... 29 more fields]
+- *Filter (isnotnull(eventID#936) && (cast(eventID#936 as int) = 1))
+- *FileScan parquet default.events[buyDetails.capacity#923,buyDetails.clearingNumber#924,buyDetails.leavesQty#925L,buyDetails.liquidityCode#926,buyDetails.orderID#927,buyDetails.side#928,cancelQty#929L,capacity#930,clearingNumber#931,contraClearingNumber#932,desiredLeavesQty#933L,displayPrice#934,displayQty#935L,eventID#936,eventTimestamp#937L,exchange#938,executionCodes#939,fillID#940,handlingInstructions#941,initiator#942,leavesQty#943L,nbbPrice#944,nbbQty#945L,nboPrice#946,... 29 more fields] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/home/asehgal/data/events], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(eventID)], ReadSchema: struct<buyDetails.capacity:string,buyDetails.clearingNumber:string,buyDetails.leavesQty:bigint,bu...
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you see the statistics in the physical plan, where do you have this information from?

Comment: I went through this documentation for Apache Spark https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/spark-sql/cbo.html and https://databricks.com/blog/2017/08/31/cost-based-optimizer-in-apache-spark-2-2.html

Comment: Tried with spark 2.3, also no statistics in query plan (and also not in Spark UI)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, the stats are not visible in `df.explain(true)`. I played around a bit, and could print statistics using `println(df.queryExecution.stringWithStats)`, full example :

```
val ss = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("TestCBO")
  .config("spark.sql.cbo.enabled",true)
  .getOrCreate()

import ss.implicits._

val df1 = ss.range(10000L).toDF("i")
df1.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("table1")

val df2 = ss.range(100000L).toDF("i")
df2.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("table2")

ss.sql("ANALYZE TABLE table1 COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS i")
ss.sql("ANALYZE TABLE table2 COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS i")

val df = ss.table("table1").join(ss.table("table2"), "i")
  .where($"i" > 1000)

println(df.queryExecution.stringWithStats)
```

gives

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [i#2554L], Statistics(sizeInBytes=147.2 KB, rowCount=9.42E+3, hints=none)
+- Join Inner, (i#2554L = i#2557L), Statistics(sizeInBytes=220.8 KB, rowCount=9.42E+3, hints=none)
   :- Filter (isnotnull(i#2554L) && (i#2554L > 1000)), Statistics(sizeInBytes=140.6 KB, rowCount=9.00E+3, hints=none)
   :  +- Relation[i#2554L] parquet, Statistics(sizeInBytes=156.3 KB, rowCount=1.00E+4, hints=none)
   +- Filter ((i#2557L > 1000) && isnotnull(i#2557L)), Statistics(sizeInBytes=1546.9 KB, rowCount=9.90E+4, hints=none)
      +- Relation[i#2557L] parquet, Statistics(sizeInBytes=1562.5 KB, rowCount=1.00E+5, hints=none)
```

This is not shown in standard `df.explain`, because this fires (Dataset.scala):

```
ExplainCommand(queryExecution.logical, extended = true) //  cost = false in this constructor
```

To enable the output of costs, we can invoke this `ExplainCommand` ourself:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExplainCommand
val explain = ExplainCommand(df.queryExecution.logical, extended = true, cost = true)
ss.sessionState.executePlan(explain).executedPlan.executeCollect().foreach {
  r => println(r.getString(0))
}
```

Here you could also enable the output of the generated code (set `codegen = true`)

alternatively, this gives a similar output

```
df // join of two dataframes and filter
 .registerTempTable("tmp")
ss.sql("EXPLAIN COST select * from tmp").show(false)
```

To see statistics in SparkUI, you must go to SQL-tab, then select the corresponding query (in this case `df.show()`):

[image]

Comment: Looks good! but are these stats correct to some extent for you or not? It shows me stats but the results are pretty random even after comput stats for columns.

Comment: Hey @RaphaelRoth, can you share the properties that you set in spark conf. Also did you analyse all the columns of the table before running the Explain cost?

Comment: @RajatMishra I added a complete example